# MATLAB: Finding eigenvectors

Tags: matlab, eigenvector

Say I have a matrix that I have already found the eigenvalues and plugged in. For example

```
A =[4 -2; -2 1]
```

What would I use to get out the eigenvector `[2; 1]`? There is `eig()` that seems to solve it as an eigenvalue equation from the start. The matrix A is just an example. I need to solve for a larger 6x6 matrix that already has the eigenvalues plugged in. I hope the question is clear

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`[V,D] = eig(A)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html).

> `[V,D] = eig(___)` returns two optional outputs for any of the previous input syntaxes. D is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues. **V is a matrix whose columns are the corresponding right eigenvectors**.

Comment: I guess i wasn't clear. Eig() finds the eigenvalues and vectors of the matrix. I have a matrix with the eigenvalues already plugged into the eigenvalue equation. So I don't need the eigenvectors of the current matrix, I just need to write the matrix in vector form, like in the steps of finding the eigenvectors. I know I could just use eig() if I had the original matrix. I was just wondering if there was a way to write a matrix in vector form (the determinant would have to be zero for this to work i think)

Comment: @user42278: That's really not clear.  What is the "vector form of a matrix"?  What do you mean by you have "a matrix with the eigenvalues already plugged into the eigenvalue equation"?  If you have the eigenvalues, but not the original matrix, then of course you can't determine the eigenvectors.  So it would be helpful to add some meaningful example to your question.

Comment: I guess I don't know what I was getting at. It's probably not as useful as I was thinking. What i was trying to ask was, if you look at matrix A in my question, is there a function that will give you a vector [2;1]

Comment: @user42278: What is `[2;1]`?

Comment: a vector with elements 2 and and 1

Comment: @user42278: Yes.  But what is the relevance of it?

Comment: @user42278 You have to explain to us, how is `[2,1]` computed for the matrix. How are they related?